# Publishing website but not removing files from one of the folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How can I publish MVC 5 application and replace all the files except of one folder? Basically in that folder I'm holding pictures which user is adding dynamically and I don't want to remove them every time I made a change to the website style or logic.

I'm using VS2013.

Comment: How are you publishing now where this isn't the case?  I believe the Visual Studio publish options wizard includes some options like "replace all files" or "replace only updated files."  It sounds like you want the latter.  As general advice, I'd recommend separating your application from your data in order to avoid issues like this.  The application itself should contain anything persistent and should be something that can be replaced in its entirety.

Comment: Thanks I'm thinking of removing this folder out of my application files, but will take a while, that is why I have asked:)

Comment: If changing the folder is anything more than a configuration setting in the application then that's something which should be fixed as soon as possible :)  Dependencies should be abstracted and easily changed.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I know of is to remove that folder from your solution.  But this may not work if you actually have content that is not dynamically added in that folder already (IE content that is needed for the solution).

Comment: No I don't have anything else in that folder which is dynamically added, but the folder is located inside the folder Content where I have all my css files.

Comment: is the folder included in your solution now?